How to compute the set of all solutions for a variable x under certain assumptions in SageMath
Consider the equation:
4 + 21 = 5
Compute the set of all solutions

under the following assumptions:
The equation is defined over the set of natural numbers (

N).
The equation is defined over the set of integers (

Z).
The equation is defined over the set of rational numbers (

Q).
I tried find_root(4* + 21 == 5, , 1, oo) but it didn't work as expected.
